# a Ruby script to use gmail RESTful API

Tags: ruby, terminal, google-oauth, gmail-api

you may help me here.
I want to write a script using Ruby, which sends emails on behalf of a user who gives permission to send emails to his contacts using gmail restful api ([link to view](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/overview)). So I found [Gmail API Client Library for Ruby](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/ruby/apis/gmail/v1), and I am getting stuck while trying to use it.

Now my question is which would is the best way to make a script using the gmail API, which will ask the user permission to send email on his behalf and save the access token, then fetch all his contact email addresses and any other permitted info  in json preferably and finally setup the system to save a given email content file on his behalf to a selected friend/friends.How will I authenticate the users accounts from the terminal? will it be [Simple API access (API keys)](https://developers.google.com/console/help/new/#usingkeys) or [Authorized API access (OAuth 2.0)](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2)?? whats the difference by the way?

Please advise the best tools, and other resources.

Answer (score 1):

Use Oauth2 as it says in the API docs:
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/about-auth

If you have more specific questions, please write them.  As it is now your question seems a bit general.

See: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2#installed for examples on how to do Oauth2 authentication from different environments.

Comment: Yes, one of the problem was how I was going to ask the user to authenticate and its not a web application. it is a script running on terminal

Comment: (Unfortunately, I believe (Google's) Oauth2 setup here requires a browser somewhere to do the one-time initial setup to get the refresh token that can be used indefinitely.)